# When is this Class D airspace not Class D airspace?

Tags: airspace, aeronautical-charts, class-d-airspace, class-g-airspace, chart-supplement

The Terminal Area Chart (TAC) shows the Class D airspace for Los Angeles International Airport (KLAX) [view the full TAC](http://skyvector.com/?ll=33.94706055709572,-118.37448926078&chart=114&zoom=3). I have highlighted in green the north and south portions of the Class D airspace. The surface area directly over KLAX airport is Class B airspace.  The note - "See NOTAMs/Supplement for Class D eff hrs" is highlighted in green on the left side with arrows pointing to the two Class D areas (2700 and 2500).

This note suggests that at certain times, these two KLAX Class D areas **may not be effective**.

The excerpt just below the TAC is from [FAA Order 7400.11 - Airspace Designations and Reporting Points](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/7400_11A.pdf) and describes the official dimensions of the KLAX Class D airspace and also indicates it (Class D) **may not be continuously effective**.

The next to last section below is an excerpt from the [Chart Supplement Southwest U.S.](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/)  (just the pertinent part). The Airspace description shows it is Class B airspace **and** Class D airspace with "...**other times CLASS G**"

The final section below is a 2012 FAA Notice [(NOTC 3900)](http://www.faasafety.gov/spans/noticeView.aspx?nid=3900) announcing the **activation of** **LAX Class D airspace**, validating that LAX has Class D airspace north and south of its runways.

My question is: When are these two (2700 msl and 2500 msl) Class D airspace sections (bordered in green) other than Class D?

[image]

---

### FAA NOTICE NOTC 3900 - LAX CLASS D Airspace Activation

[image]

Comment: These two areas are part of the Mini Route that is in effect during normal tower operations for Santa Monica and Hawthorne. Southbound you are under the control of Santa Monica tower then handed off to LAX to transition the Class B over the runways. Northbound you are under control of Hawthorne  tower then handed off to LAX tower. When those towers are closed, the Mini Route is not available and the airspace reverts to G.

Comment: JScarry - Check the coordinates out above showing these two areas are part of the LAX Class D airspace.  (see the 7400.11 above).  These two areas belong to LAX Tower.  Also, see this notice regarding what facility the two areas belong to: https://www.faasafety.gov/spans/noticeView.aspx?nid=3900

Comment: Not disagreeing with you. LAX tower controls the mini route and only allows transitions when the other two towers can do the handoff. Normally it is at 2,500 but you can be assigned lower altitudes. Normally you fly the radial as well, but you can be given vectors.

Comment: I've withdrawn my answer based on your comment, but I recommend adding the relevant part of that notice into the question body as I've missed it. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @ymb1 - I can do that, but if you  check the coordinates of the official description of the LAX Class D airspace above (clearly shown in the description as belonging to LAX) those two areas as shown outlined in green are what is being described.  I realize that it's an onerous task to plot the coordinates, but obviously LAX has Class D airspace somewhere or else it would not show at all in the specific 7400.11 Class D description. Thanks.

Comment: @JScarry I think that your comment should be an answer here. And Chart supplement for LAX just don't contain this data for the some reason, nobody knows why.

Answer (score 4):

Great question. The short answer to your question is "Full Time." Ultimately that Class D airspace will be incorporated into the LAX Class B, but there is a lot of red tape involved so step one was to add the Class D extensions, then it will be incorpoated into LAX Class B at a later date. Its a big deal, Title 14 CFR Part 71 had to be amended, here is the Federal Register page that explains the rule change. By the way, you're not alone in being confused about the effective hours, apparently that language was erroneously included in the charts and had to be removed.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

According to Foreflight:

> Activation Continuously (excl holidays)

This is specifically for the areas you indicated.  Otherwise, generally, class D is not class D when the tower that controls the class D is closed.  Usually this is every night.